# MVC 5 Application Azure/IIS Error after Idle Time-Out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, http-status-code-404

Having an issue when deploying MVC application to azure/IIS. After immediately deploying, application works as intended.

After ~20 minutes of inactivity on azure and IIS error is shown:

**404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Issue occurs when deployed to Azure after ~20 minutes

Error is not shown on IIS when application pool is changed to SUSPEND instead of TERMINATE. This is not the ideal solution

Helpful comments:

Application was working fine until about two weeks ago.

Major change that seems to be part of the cause is removing old Web Matrix dependency for authentication and replaced with Asp Net Identity 2.2.1

I have tried everything I could think of thus far. 
Solutions such as pinging the application every X amount of time to prevent idle time out does not seem like the correct solution since application was working on azure and IIS previously.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to try to switch back to the old Web Matrix dependency and also turn on AlwaysOn setting for your Azure web app if it's app service plan tier is Basic or above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything, the issue was having a controller called Reports. My guess is somehow IIS, and Azure have this routing reserved for SSRS. This issue was somehow causing both the apps deployment on IIS and Azure to fail at some moment.